# Heroku Japanese text garbled

Tags: java, heroku, character-encoding

I'm trying out Heroku for the first time and I'm following the Java tutorial.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#introduction

If I add Japanese text to the index.ftl file, it won't display correctly.
Text file encoding in Eclipse is already UTF-8, and I also added `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` for good measure.

My problem is the Japanese text hard-coded in the ftl file, and the input data submitted to my servlet.

The reverse (Japanese text from the servlet) works fine after adding the following to the pom.xml:

Under the maven plugins:`<encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>`
and inside the project itself:

```
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Comment: Sorry, data submitted to my servlet works fine, but won't display properly on windows cmd console (Where I ran "heroku local web" command. Probably some other problem... but the hard-coded Japanese text in the .ftl file is still an issue...

Comment: I did some more testing, It works when uploading to the server, but is garbled if using the heroku local web command.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to the `java` command in your `Procfile`.

Comment: Didn't work, also tried adding <#ftl encoding="utf-8"> at the top of the freemarker but still no change...